# Embedding power bi report inside Databricks notebook is not displaying report

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, powerbi, databricks

I was trying this new feature which allows Power BI reports to be embedded inside Jupyter notebooks from this link : https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-power-bi-in-jupyter-notebooks/

However, after following all the steps correctly, the report is not displayed at all
there are no errors , nothing

just blank after running the code :

```
report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=device_auth)

report
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you have already found the solution but updating the thread. I experienced the same, tried out many options, nothing worked. But refreshing the browser (Notebook) by pressing CTRL+F5 after the authentication solved the issue.

Comment: No, this issue is still unresolved